# Java parsing a string into an int, then a null

Tags: java

Got this code:

```
            System.out.println("Introduce salary: ");
            Scanner alpha8 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String salary = alpha8.nextLine();
            int salaryNew = 0;
            if(salary .isEmpty()){
                salary = null;
            }else{
                salaryNew = Integer.parseInt(salary);
            }
```

How can i make this to output only 1 variable from the IF? Because if the introduced value is null (blank space from scanner, like enter) sets salary to null wich i use later on.

The thing is that i either need a "null" or an "int value".

In the "else" i cannot do this:

```
salary = Integer.parseInt(salary);
```

because id get an error, neither i can parse int into to null.

And this methodto convert dates:

```
public static Date changeDate(String introducedDate) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date sqlDate = sdf.parse(introducedDate);
    java.sql.Date newSqlDate= new java.sql.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
    return newSqlDate;
}
```

If introducedDate is null it will throw an exception, how can i change that method to return NULL if introduced date is NULL too?

Comment: Using an `if` statement?

Comment: if(introduced date == null){return null} like this? but there would be 2 returns in that method coz there muset be an else too

Comment: Exactly like that, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

> The thing is that i either need a "null" or an "int value".

If you want to have an integer value which is nullable, use the wrapper class `Integer`:

```
Integer salaryNew = null;
if (!salary.isEmpty()) {
    salaryNew = Integer.parseInt(salary);
}
```

---

**Part 2**

> If introducedDate is null it will throw an exception, how can i change that method to return NULL if introduced date is NULL too?

You need to check the value of the parameter before you do any work on it (See @nem's answer, since he beat me to that half).

Comment: strange, getting null pointer exception, i must set that salaryNew to an entity, like employee.setSalary(salaryNew) and getting null pinter lol. Works with date but not with salary

Comment: @Alpha2k I would expect that the salary type inside the employee is `int`, which as you've already discovered cannot be assigned a `null` value.  When the compiler tries to unbox the `null`, it'll throw a NPE.  Do you really need `salaryNew` to be nullable?

Comment: even tough i changed the employee to Integer salary i still get a null pointer in the prepared statement: pstmt.setInt(7, employee.getSal());

Comment: @Alpha2k what value do you expect to be written to the database is the salary is `null`?  If the database is expecting a number, you'll need to give it one.  Do you have some sort of "no salary here" error code you can enter?  If so, you can check for a `null` parameter in `setSal()` and assign that error value.

Comment: yea kinda need it nullable max for example when searching with ranges. User may define lowestPrice but if highestPrice is not introduced by user is considered as null.

Comment: also if i want to get all users from database if there is one that has null value as Salary im screwed and i cant retreive that line... basicly i want to select * from employees even if theyr salary is null

Comment: @Alpha2k This discussion is exceeding what works well as comments.  You might want write up the database issue as a separate question, and link back to this one for context.

Answer (score 1):

Check out @azurefrog's answer for your first question.

> If introducedDate is null it will throw an exception, how can i change that method to return NULL if introduced date is NULL too?

```
public static Date changeDate(String introducedDate) throws ParseException {
    if(introducedDate == null) {  // ADD THIS CHECK
        return null;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date sqlDate = sdf.parse(introducedDate);
    java.sql.Date newSqlDate= new java.sql.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
    return newSqlDate;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine our answers...? ;-)

Comment: @azurefrog i don't think so haha then again, we both got an upvote for a half-answer so I guess that is a combination haha

Answer (score 0):

you can do -

```
if(salary != null && ! salary.isEmpty() )
{
     return Integer.parseInt(salary);
}else{
      return null;
}
```

for your second part add this if condition before doing any date format-

```
   if(introducedDate == null) { 
        return null;
    }
```